# Show Multiple Value With Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 db 'srtptr' and 'deskripsisrt' and I want to show them with modal bootstrap
I successfully show from 'srtptr' but I don't know how to show from 'deskripsisrt',..

this my db 'deskripsisrt'

```
+--------------+------------------+-----------+
|    id_des    |     deskripsi    |   id_srt  |
+--------------+------------------+-----------+
|      1       |       Test 4     |     4     |
|      2       |       Test 2     |     4     |
+--------------+------------------+-----------+
```

I want to show multiple values on my modal.

**Modal script:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModals" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: 600; overflow-y: scroll;">

                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="removeWarning">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                    Anda yakin ingin menghapus user ini
                </div>
                <br>
                <form class="form-horizontal" id="formUser"  method="post" target="blank">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="type" name="type">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id_srt" name="id_srt">
                    <input id="desc" value="1" type="hidden" >

                        <span style="font-weight: bold">Kepada PT</span>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tujuan_srt" id="tujuan_srt" value="" title="Tujuan Surat" placeholder="Tujuan Surat" maxlength="25" size="100">
                        </div>
                    </br>
                        <span style="font-weight: bold">Kepada Nama</span>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kepada_srt" id="kepada_srt" value="" title="Tujuan Surat" placeholder="Tujuan Surat" maxlength="25" size="100">
                    </div>
                    </br>
                        <span style="font-weight: bold">Tanggal</span>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="tanggal" class="form-control" id="tanggal" value="<?php echo $fungsi->Tanggal('tgl').' '.$fungsi->Tanggal('blnL').' '.$fungsi->Tanggal('THN'); ?>" title="Tanggal Pembayaran" readonly="readonly" size="100">
                        </div>  

                    </br>
                    <div class="col-md-6 konten "></br>
                        <span style="font-weight: bold">Deskripsi</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6 konten " style="Text-align: Right;"></br>
                            <button type="button" onclick="tambahDesc(); return false;" style="cursor:pointer; font-size:8pt; border-radius:2px; min-width:10px; border:0px; background:#4D4D4D; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;">Tambah Deskripsi</button>
                        </div>

            <table border="1" style="width:30%" id="test">
   <tr><td>deskripsi</td></tr>
      **I WANT TO SHOW VALUE FROM DB 'deskripsisrt' HERE!!**
               </table> 
                        <div id="divDesc"> </div>
                </br></br></br></br>
                </form>
                </div>



            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="btn1" class="btn btn-default" style="align:left">Cetak</button>
                <button type="button" onClick="submitUser()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" onClick="clearModals()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**AJAX Code:**

```
//Show Modal 
function showModals( id_srt )
{
    waitingDialog.show();
    clearModals();


    // For Execute Data (EDIT & DELETE)
    if( id_srt )
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "crud.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id_srt:id_srt,type:"get"},
            success: function(res) {
                waitingDialog.hide();
                setModalData( res );
            }
        });
    }

    // FOR ADD Data
    else
    {
        $("#myModals").modal("show");
        $("#myModalLabel").html("New User");
        $("#type").val("new"); 
        waitingDialog.hide();
    }
}

//Show Data On Modal For Edit 
function setModalData( data )
{

    $("#myModalLabel").html(data.id_srt);
    $("#id_srt").val(data.id_srt);
    $("#type").val("edit");
    $("#tujuan_srt").val(data.tujuan_srt);
    $("#kepada_srt").val(data.kepada_srt);
    $("#tanggal").val(data.tanggal);
    $("#myModals").modal("show");
}


//For Execute EDIT/DELETE/ADD NEW To DB
function submitUser()
{
    var formData = $("#formUser").serialize();
    waitingDialog.show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "crud.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            dTable.ajax.reload(); // Automatic Reload Table Page 
            waitingDialog.hide();   
        }
    });
}

$('#btn1').click(function()
{
    $('#formUser').attr('action','setcetak.php');
    $('#formUser').submit();
    }
);

//Delete Data
function deleteUser( id_srt )
{
    clearModals();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "crud.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {id_srt:id_srt,type:"get"},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#removeWarning").show();
            $("#myModalLabel").html("Delete User");
            $("#id_srt").val(data.id_srt);
            $("#type").val("delete");
            $("#tujuan_srt").val(data.tujuan_srt).attr("disabled","true");
            $("#kepada_srt").val(data.kepada_srt).attr("disabled","true");
            $("#tanggal").val(data.tanggal).attr("disabled","true");
            $("#myModals").modal("show");
            waitingDialog.hide();           
        }
    });
}

//Clear Modal
function clearModals()
{
    $("#removeWarning").hide();
    $("#tujuan_srt").val("").removeAttr( "disabled" );
    $("#kepada_srt").val("").removeAttr( "disabled" );
    $("#tanggal").val("").removeAttr( "disabled" );

}

// ADD Description Field
function tambahDesc() {
    var desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;
    var stre;
    stre="<div id='srow" + desc + "'><div class='col-md-12 konten' style='Text-align: Right;'></br><a href='#' style=\"color:#EC090D; cursor:pointer; text-align: Right;\" onclick='hapusElemen(\"#srow" + desc + "\"); return false;'>hapus</a><div class='input-group'><textarea rows='6' cols='100' type='text' class='desce form-control' name='deskripsi[]' placeholder='deskripsi' size='100'></textarea></br></div></div></div>";
    $("#divDesc").append(stre); 
    desc = (desc-1) + 1;
    document.getElementById("desc").value = desc;
}

//Delete Description Field
function hapusElemen(desc) {
    $(desc).remove();
} 

$(function(id_srt) {

    var data_table = "";
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "crud.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{id_srt:id_srt,type:"getdes"},
        success: function(data) {
        for (var i =0; i<data.length; i++){
        data_table +="<tr> <td> "+data[i].deskripsi+"</td></tr>";
        }
        $('#test').append(data_table);  
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller Code :**

```
<?php
require 'config/action.php';
$fungsi = new Fungsi();
//Connection Database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","kw");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

switch ($_POST['type']) {

    //Tampilkan Data 
    case "get":

        $SQL = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM srtptr WHERE id_srt='".$_POST['id_srt']."'");
        $return = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($return);
        break;

    case "getdes": // NEW CODE This Show a table 'deskripsisrt'

        $SQL  =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM deskripsisrt WHERE id_srt = '".$_POST['id_srt']."'");
        while ($return = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $return;
        }
        echo json_encode($rows);
        break;

    //Tambah Data   
    case "new":

        $SQL = mysqli_query($con, 
                                "INSERT INTO kwitansi SET 
                                    kwnum='".$_POST['kwnum']."', 
                                    tglkw='".$_POST['tglkw']."', 
                                    dari='".$_POST['dari']."',
                                    penerima='".$_POST['penerima']."',
                                    nominal='".$_POST['nominal']."',
                                    pembayaran='".$_POST['pembayaran']."'
                            ");
        if($SQL){
            echo json_encode("OK");
        }
        break;

    //Edit Data 
    case "edit":

        $SQL = mysqli_query($con, 
                                "UPDATE srtptr SET 
                                    tujuan_srt='".$_POST['tujuan_srt']."', 
                                    kepada_srt='".$_POST['kepada_srt']."',
                                    tanggal='".$_POST['tanggal']."'
                                WHERE id_srt='".$_POST['id_srt']."'
                            ");
        if($SQL){
            echo json_encode("OK");
        }           
        break;

    //Hapus Data    
    case "delete":

        $SQL = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM srtptr WHERE id_srt='".$_POST['id_srt']."'");
        if($SQL){
            echo json_encode("OK");
        }           
        break;
}   
?>
```

I think this needs a loop on ajax but I don't know to make the loop ajax.

Comment: what is the structure of your data  returned from controller

Comment: sory my bad english , are you mean a what a table data of my data returned from controler?

Comment: I mean the result returned from server . You can check that in the network tab . I want the structure of the data returned in Json

Comment: Sory i really noob on ajax and json code,.. i update the post with full code controller,.. really sory the controler give from my friend,.. before i use PHP script to show value from table 'deskripsisrt' to form but the code never get value from post "id_srt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the json coming from controller is like this

```
    [
     {"id_des":45,"deskripsi":"test","id_srt":2},
     {"id_des":46,"deskripsi":"test1","id_srt":3},
     {"id_des":47,"deskripsi":"test2","id_srt":4},
    ]

update your function of success like this 
   success: function(data) {

    $.each(data, function() {
      $.each(this, function(k, v) {
        console.log(k + " " +v);
      });
    });
   }
```

Comment: yeah iwant value like your code example {"id_des":45,"deskripsi":"test","id_srt":2}, so how i get that from my 'deskripsisrt' table ?

Comment: you need to convert it to json please look how you can dothat

Comment: Hey Yashveer Singh finaly i am done To convert Json And make show code on ajax code see last ajax code and I add to controller with Case name "getdes", see my query,.. if i select from table with id_srt 4 the case "getdes" never get ( $_POST['id_srt'] ) from my form cant you help me with this case?

Comment: Hi I am sorry I am not a php guy . So canot help you on controller side . But basicly the Idea is same what ever you need to send from controller it should be a array of certain structure which you want to show in html . Once you get the array then you can loop through array as I answered

Comment: Yeah ,.. thanks to solved my problem,.. So from now i know a basicaly ajax thanks